# How in webview (url on website) call userMedia javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, getusermedia

I need to call the camera from js in the android webview, but for some reason there is such an error in the logs:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'getUserMedia' on 'MediaDevices': The object must have a callable @@iterator property.
```

Google searches turned up nothing, I requested permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Everything else works fine, setJavascriptEnabled is enabled